# flask html link for downloading file

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I'm building an websites that allows the user to download files from my server.
I wrote a route for serving the file:

```
@api.route('/download_results/<path:filename>')
def download_results(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename, as_attachment=True)
```

if i try to use an html tag like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" herf="http://localhost/api/download_results/1234567890/results.zip" download="results.zip">Download results</a>
```

it doesn't work. but if i add an event listener in jQuery:

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     window.location.href = location.origin + '/api/download_results/' + data.parsedData[0];
 });
```

it works and i can download but i get a warning:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/x-zip-compressed:
>   "http://localhost/api/download_results/1234567890/results.zip".

Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong and how i can solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: It might be because you're missing the port in the address?

Comment: i tried to add the port and i get the same behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in what should be the `href` attribute of your anchor tag.